# OS X Server 3.0 - DNS & Server Names

Tags: macos, osx-server, dns, hosts

I have two Mac Mini's running Mavericks Server. The hostnames for them are as follows:

- macsvr01.mydomain.com
- macsvr02.mydomain.com

I want to be able to access macsvr02 by going to cloud.mydomain.com as it provides cloud services. What do I need to do to be able to access the same server from two different hostnames? I'm assuming it would be an alias?

I want to limit access to specific services based on the host and domain name. For example, macsvr02.mydomain.com should allow access to Profile Manger via `www.mydomain.com/profilemanager`. But Profile Manager should not be accessible via `cloud.mydomain.com/profilemanager`. I'd like to use the `cloud.mydomain.com` FQDN for Contacts/Calendar/Messages service access only.

Comment: DNS isn't going to be sufficient here. You can't do service-level filtering with DNS alone. You'll need a firewall to allow or deny service access based on the domain and hostname used to be the incoming packets to connect to your machine.

Answer (score 1):

[Domain Name System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System), or DNS,

> translates easily memorized domain names to the numerical IP addresses

For what you are asking all that is necesary is two DNS records specifying the same IP address. You could make your Mac Mini Mavericks server aware of the multiple domain names, using an alias, but it is not an absolute necessity to have the functionality you seek.

The questions that remain are:

- Whom or what is handling your domain names, and translating your public address to the IP of your server? Your ISP?
- Did you reserve and purchase your desired domain names?

---

Possibly of some use to you is this tutorial, [How to Configure OS X Mavericks Server App 3.X Basic DNS and Server Settings](http://m.wikihow.com/Configure-OS-X-Mavericks-Server-App-3.X-Basic-DNS-and-Server-Settings)

You'll find a more advanced an in-depth explanation of DNS [here](https://www.appliedtrust.com/resources/infrastructure/understanding-dns-essential-knowledge-for-all-it-professionals)

Comment: I did use an alias, but I can't seem to limit it to specific services. For example, macsvr02.mydomain.com has Profile Manger. I wanted to access it via www.mydomain.com/profilemanager only. However, I can also use cloud.mydomain.com/profilemanager as well and I do not want that. I want cloud.mydomain.com for Contacts/Calendar/Messages only.

Comment: @user78429 = catchy username! ;-) Are you asking for specific setup instructions for your Mavericks server? Because while there are settings, I'm not sure what you place there will necessarily be distributed to other DNS servers (though I have had development DNS servers apparently publish and advertise DNS names unintentionally when I was learning about OS X Server using Panther Server, quite some time ago, but now OS X Server software is completely different)

Comment: @user78429: DNS simply provides a way to find the server, not a way to control what services are offered. There might be a way to accomplish what you want in some other way, but you'll have to explain what you're actually trying to accomplish (and avoid the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem#66378)).

Comment: @GordonDavisson — With emphasis, I thank you for that link!!!!       ^---------